# Should I use different browsers for surfing and logging into accounts?

Tags: authentication, web-browser, logging, browser-extensions, credentials

I use web in different ways, i.e.:

*a)* to log into my accounts (email, google, social, forums, etc.);

*b)* for downloading softwares;

*c)* for surfing trusted websites;

*d)* for surfing websites which I don't know whether they are safe or not;

I do the *b)*, *c)* and *d)* with Chrome and added add-ons to block scripts, advertisement and trackers. I cannot use Sandoxie anymore because of compatibility troubles.

Since Chrome is not sandboxed and my safety is only relying on add-ons, should I still use a different browser for logging into my accounts or it doesn't matter?

In other terms: as far as a virus attacks me through an untrusted website, will my credentials be more protected if they are not saved on the same browser?

Comment: You could use 'TOR browser' which is meant to protect your privacy and leave no traces behind. Try downloading the TOR bundle and give it a go.

Comment: As far as I remember it is not recommended do download files with Tor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Malware needs to be dropped to your host to scrape the saved passwords, it can't be done by the malicious website itself.

Unless the malware (say, dropped by an exploit kit) targets only a particular browser, all the popular browsers are vulnerable because all the saved passwords are stored somewhere on your computer. I think in general saving passwords on a separate browser does slightly increase the security but there are better ways to protect these credentials (e.g. password managers and protection against exploit kits).

If your concern is saving the credentials in the browser maybe you should take a look in how different browsers manage saved passwords and choose a browser according to that:
http://raidersec.blogspot.se/2013/06/how-browsers-store-your-passwords-and.html
http://www.pcworld.com/article/261259/can_you_trust_your_browser_with_your_passwords_.html
(Please note these links are a bit old and some information might be outdated)